Strange extra arrow behavior in tikz because xshift
The following code gives me a strange arrow:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, arrows, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
  \node (P)              {$(x+3)(x-5)$};
  \node[anchor = west] (E1) at (P.east) {$=$};
  \node[anchor = west] (D) at (E1.east) {$x^2+3x-5x-15$};
  \node[anchor = west] (E2) at (D.east) {$=$};
  \node[anchor = west] (R) at (E2.east) {$x^2-2x-15$};
  \draw[->]
    ([xshift=-1.5em, yshift=1em]P.center) edge [bend left=15] node[anchor=south] {Multiply} (R);
}
\end{document}

What I get is this : as you can see, on the left part, there is an unwanted arrow. It is probably because I used the "xshift" parameter. How do I get rid of this extra arrow on the left?


In this case, the tips=proper key is used to draw arrows only where they are required.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bending, arrows, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tips=proper]
 \node (P)              {$(x+3)(x-5)$};
  \node[anchor = west] (E1) at (P.east) {$=$};
  \node[anchor = west] (D) at (E1.east) {$x^2+3x-5x-15$};
  \node[anchor = west] (E2) at (D.east) {$=$};
  \node[anchor = west] (R) at (E2.east) {$x^2-2x-15$};
  \draw[->]
    ([xshift=-1.5em, yshift=1ex]P.north) edge [bend left=15] node[anchor=south] {Multiply} (R);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}



Great, that's perfect! I didn't know about this command, even though I had a look at the documentation (https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows). Thanks a lot!
